# How to make a collision detector for a class of items

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-physics

Im working on a project game and I want to see if a div "rope" hits one of my pictures `class='Fish1'`.

I managed to get it to work by using `document.GetElementsById("fish")` but when I change it to `document.getElementsByClassName('fish1')` it gives me an error saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'getBoundingClientRect') at checkCollision

How can i fix this error? Also how can I check the height during the transition of a div and have it give me the height that it is at that point in the transition?

I've tried this:

```
function checkCollision(rope, fishy) {
  var line = rope;
  var fishy = document.getElementsByClassName('fish1');
  var ropeRect = line.getBoundingClientRect();
  for (var i = 0; i < fishy.length; i++) {
    var fishyRect = fishy[i].getBoundingClientRect(i);
  }
  return (ropeRect.right >= fishyRect.left &&
          ropeRect.left <= fishyRect.right) &&
         (ropeRect.bottom >= fishyRect.top &&
          ropeRect.top <= fishyRect.bottom);
}
```

And this is what worked for the id only:

```
function checkCollision(line, fishy) {
  var line = rope;
  var fishy = document.getElementById('fish');
  var lineRect = line.getBoundingClientRect();
  var fishyRect = fishy.getBoundingClientRect();

  return (lineRect.right >= fishyRect.left &&
          lineRect.left <= fishyRect.right) &&
         (lineRect.bottom >= fishyRect.top &&
          lineRect.top <= fishyRect.bottom);
}
```

Comment: you are looping through all fishy elements and while doing so you set a new variable fishyRect. After you did that you have your return statement using only the last fishyRect. This doesn't seem correct.

Comment: if we wanted to address the problems in the function provided: you used `getElementsByClassName` with the arg `fish1` that it's clearly an id and not a class; you pass `i` to `getBoundingClientRect`; comparing `left` against `right` and `top` against `bottom` is cringe; ... anyway the very first thing I said is the most critical

Answer (score 0):

#### Checking collision:

You can check if two elements overlap by using conditions that compare their x,y coords also involving their width, height:

```
//returns true if obj1 and obj2 collided, otherwise false
function checkCollision(obj1, obj2) {  
  const rect1 = obj1.getBoundingClientRect();    
  const rect2 = obj2.getBoundingClientRect();      
  return (rect1.x + rect1.width >= rect2.x && rect1.x <= rect2.x + rect2.width) &&
         (rect1.y + rect1.height >= rect2.y && rect1.y <= rect2.y + rect2.height)
}
```

#### Moving the elements:

Once you have the function, you can call it inside your loop after changing the position of the elements at each iteration.

You didn't share any other detail apart the not working `checkCollision` function so I have no idea how did you perform the motion or probably you didn't at all yet.

Here I used `Window.requestAnimationFrame()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

> The window.requestAnimationFrame() method tells the browser that you
> wish to perform an animation and requests that the browser calls a
> specified function to update an animation before the next repaint. The
> method takes a callback as an argument to be invoked before the
> repaint.

Here in this example, I animate a group of `.fish` elements over a sin wave crossing a line in the middle. Every time an element overlaps with the rope, it calls the function `collisionOccurred` printing on console its `id` property.

Since you have the exact element partecipating to the event you are free to fetch anything about it like for example the exact position where it is at in that instant (or the height you were expecting to know).

Later I also added the events `fishEnter` and `fishLeave` that fire respectively when the element enters and leaves the rope area.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('body');
const rope = document.getElementById('rope');
const fishes = document.getElementsByClassName('fish');

let start = null;
let containerWidth, containerHeight;

beginAnimation();

//begins the fishes animation
function beginAnimation() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(moveFish);
}

//returns the x,y coords of a sin function
function getSin(millisecondsPast, cycleDuration = 2000) {

  //ranging 0-1 in the span of cycleDuration (ms)
  const progress = (millisecondsPast % cycleDuration) / cycleDuration;
  //=~6.28
  const twoPi = 2 * Math.PI;

  //x ranging from 0-6.28 in the span of cycleDuration
  const x = twoPi * progress;
  //sin(x) (radius=1)
  const y = Math.sin(x);

  return {
    //[0-1] (in the span of cycleDuration ms)
    x: progress,
    //[-1,+1] 
    y: y
  }
}

//moves all the fishes following a sin wave
function moveFish(timestamp) {

  const containerWidth = parseInt(container.offsetWidth);
  const containerHeight = parseInt(container.offsetHeight);

  //keep track of the animation progress
  if (!start) start = timestamp;
  let progress = timestamp - start;

  //for all the fishes
  for (fish of fishes) {

    //calculate the x and y of a sin wave
    //spread across the container width in the 0-2pi space
    const duration = parseInt(fish.dataset.duration);
    const vertical = parseInt(fish.dataset.verticalspan);

    const sin = getSin(progress, duration);
    let x = sin.x * containerWidth;
    let y = sin.y * (vertical/2) + (containerHeight / 2);

    //change the position of the current fish      
    fish.style.left = `${x}px`;
    fish.style.top = `${y}px`;

    const didcollide = checkCollision(rope, fish);
    const overlapping = (fish.dataset.overlapping == 'true') ? true : false;
    
    //calls fishEnter if the fish entered in the space of the rope
    if (!overlapping && didcollide) {
      fish.dataset.overlapping = 'true';
      fishEnter(fish);
    }
    //calls fishLeave if the fish left the space of the rope
    else if (overlapping && !didcollide) {
      fish.dataset.overlapping = 'false';
      fishLeave(fish);
    }
    //calls collisionOccurred if the fish collided with the rope
    if (didcollide)
      collisionOccurred(fish);
  }

  //render next iteration    
  window.requestAnimationFrame(moveFish);
}

//returns true if obj1 and obj2 collided, otherwise false
function checkCollision(obj1, obj2) {
  const rect1 = obj1.getBoundingClientRect();
  const rect2 = obj2.getBoundingClientRect();

  const didcollide =
    (rect1.x + rect1.width >= rect2.x && rect1.x <= rect2.x + rect2.width) &&
    (rect1.y + rect1.height >= rect2.y && rect1.y <= rect2.y + rect2.height);
    
  return didcollide;
}

//gets fired when the fish enters in the space of the rope
function fishEnter(target) {
  target.classList.add('crossing');
  console.log(`The fish id: ${target.id} entered in the rope space!`);
}

//gets fired when the fish leaves in the space of the rope
function fishLeave(target) {
  target.classList.remove('crossing');
  console.log(`The fish id: ${target.id} left the rope space!`);
}

//gets fired when the collision event occurs
function collisionOccurred(target) {
  //console.log(`The fish id: ${target.id} crossed the rope!`);
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#rope {
  --size: 80px;
  --border: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% + var(--border) - var(--size) / 2) ;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--size);
  background: brown;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  outline: solid var(--border) darkorange;
  color: darkorange;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.fish {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  line-height: 2rem;
  background: blue;
  font-weight: 600;
  outline: solid darkblue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.fish::after {
  content: attr(id);
  color: white;  
}

button {
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.crossing{
  background: yellow;
}

.crossing::after{
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="rope">ROPE AREA</div>

<div id="fish1" class="fish" data-duration="5000" data-verticalspan="200"></div>
<div id="fish2" class="fish" data-duration="8000" data-verticalspan="300"></div>
<div id="fish3" class="fish" data-duration="10000" data-verticalspan="100"></div>
<div id="fish4" class="fish" data-duration="3000" data-verticalspan="500"></div>
```